# Sorting position of records based on user input

Tags: php, sql, algorithm, sorting, record

I have a database that is MySQL / Php technology. I have a database that will have the following columns:

Id (primary key)
Title 
Description
Del
Date
Position
And so On....

Each row represents a ticket or a record the user adds to the database. The User can determine the position of the records by selecting an integer to put into the database (1 to n). Then when all records are displayed it will display by position number. With position one displaying first. The only rule is that there cannot be a position with the same value (there cannot be more than one record with position 1). Also user should be able to select position number upon inserting new records. Also the user should be able to change the position of any existing records or rows.

What sorting Algorithm or programming code should I use to approach this problem or task?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use a field `order int(11)`
make an alter table to table to add this field.
when the user adds a new record makes a query to retrieve the order number and the biggest max +1 week's new record.
then to choose the order of the records you can use something like: http://jqueryui.com/demos/sortable/

Comment: The user will select the position by selecting the position from a drop down menu. They can select position 1 to last position

Comment: then you populate the select with n numbers as there are records in the database user.
If the user selects `x`, you have to write a script that fetches records with `order >= x`, greater than 1 the results of the query and then add your record with `order = x`.

Comment: when you said greater than 1 the results, did you mean increment each record by 1?

Comment: how about when a record is deleted? Would it be > x l, decrement each value by 1?